# nd getting this error "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using Rechablity.h and Rechablity.h which is provided by Apple and Using these file and added some code like

```
#pragma mark Rechability method

/**
* reachabilityChanged()
* @desc Check the internet connection
* @param NSNotification note is the notification of internet state changed
*/

- (void) reachabilityChanged: (NSNotification* )note {

Reachability* curReach = [note object];
NSParameterAssert([curReach isKindOfClass: [Reachability class]]);
[self updateInterfaceWithReachability: curReach];
}

/**
* updateInterfaceWithReachability()
* @desc Update the internet connection state
* @param Reachability curReach is the instance of Reachbility
*/

- (void) updateInterfaceWithReachability: (Reachability*) curReach {

if(curReach == internetReach) {

    NetworkStatus netStatus = [curReach currentReachabilityStatus];
    BOOL connectionRequired = [curReach connectionRequired];
    NSString* statusString = @"";

    switch (netStatus) {

        case NotReachable: {

            statusString = @"Access Not Available";
            connectionRequired = NO;
            isInternetAvailable = FALSE;
            break;
        }

        case ReachableViaWWAN: {

            statusString = @"Reachable WWAN";
            isInternetAvailable = TRUE;
            break;
        }

        case ReachableViaWiFi: {

            statusString = @"Reachable WiFi";
            isInternetAvailable = TRUE;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(connectionRequired)
        statusString = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@, Connection Required", statusString];
    //UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Gmmabling Gambit" message:statusString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",nil];
    //      [alert show];
    //      [alert release];
    //NSLog(@"%@",statusString);
}
}

/**
* internetCheck()
* @desc store the internet connection state
* @return BOOL internet is available or not
*/

- (BOOL)internetCheck {

return isInternetAvailable;
}
```

Added systemConfiguration.framework and Security.framework
but having this type of error

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error usually comes up when you haven't added the `.m file` in the `bundle resources`.
So can you just cross check whether these files are added or else add the implementation file.
You can do the same by going to **Build Phases -> Compile resources and then add the .m file**

Let me know if it works:)

Hope this helps!

Comment: just expand your project and check for any files(imported libraries or any header/implementation files)that will be missing from your project(Specifically highlighted in red)

Comment: Finally I got the solution for the same thanks everyone for the support <3

Comment: Superb!It would be great if you could share the solution, for our future visitors:)

Answer (score 0):

in build settings, search with build architecture, if that value is No, replace to Yes. May be works. You have to change both project and targets.